# Python OpenCV output on Tkinter label deletion

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to delete a Tkinter label that is currently displaying a webcam stream made by OpenCV. I eventually made it to happen but not with the way I wanted because it just stops the stream but the last image outputted by the stream is still present. The code is this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def Start():
    width, height = 800, 600
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
    cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
    def show_frame():
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
        img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        lmain.imgtk = imgtk
        lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
        lmain.after(10, show_frame)
    show_frame()

root = Tk()
lmain = Label(root)
lmain.pack(side = RIGHT)

Button1 = Button(root, text = "Start", command = Start)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT)
Button2 = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = Start)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

You may notice that the function I used to stop it is the same function I used to start it, that is because I am very clueless as on how to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code, and I add some code here:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

isrunning = 0
def Start():
    global isrunning
    if isrunning == 0:
        width, height = 800, 600
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
        cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
        isrunning = 1
        lmain.pack(side = RIGHT)

        def show_frame():
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            lmain.imgtk = imgtk
            lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
            if isrunning == 1:
                lmain.after(10, show_frame)

    show_frame()

def Stop():
    global isrunning
    isrunning = 0
    lmain.pack_forget()

root = Tk()
lmain = Label(root)

Button1 = Button(root, text = "Start", command = Start)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT)
Button2 = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = Stop)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

You can find that I add a global variable `isrunning` to let the function `show_frame` check every time. If the variable `isrunning` is equal to 0, the function will stop. And I also add the function `Stop` as the callback function of the "Stop" button which contains the code `lmain.pack_forget()` to remove the label.

Since the label will be removed every time when you click the "Stop" button, I move the code for adding the label to the `Start` function. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried the code with you modification on it and I made a small tweak to it because it does the part that you can delete the label but it does not close the webcam and also I made it so you can press the "Start" again and it will still work. Anyways I appreciate your help because I used it as a basis.

The code is in my answer question post.

Answer (score 1):

The code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

isrunning = 0
def Start():
    global isrunning
    if isrunning == 0:
        global cap
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        isrunning = 1
        lmain.pack(side = RIGHT)

        def show_frame():
            _, frame = cap.read()
            frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
            cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
            img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
            imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
            lmain.imgtk = imgtk
            lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
            if isrunning == 1:
                lmain.after(10, show_frame)

    show_frame()

def Stop():
    global isrunning
    isrunning = 0
    lmain.pack_forget()

def main():
    Stop()
    Button1.invoke()
    Stop()


root = Tk()
lmain = Label(root)

Button1 = Button(root, text = "Start", command = Start)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT)
Button2 = Button(root, text = "Stop", command = main)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```